# building GStreamer Editing Services 1.2.1 (GES) on windows using Msys MinGw

Tags: mingw, development-environment, gstreamer, msys

How can I build Gstreamer Editing Services 1.2.1 on windows?

What steps I take:
1) download gstreamer-editing-services-1.2.1.tar.xz from http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/gst-editing-services/
2) unpack it two times with 7zip.
3) paste extracted "gstreamer-editing-services-1.2.1" folder and its contents to Msys user home folder - C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\Benas
4) In msys console type "cd gstreamer-editing-services-1.2.1"
5) In msys console type "./configure --prefix=$HOME"

And it says:

```
 configure: No package 'glib-2.0' found
 No package 'gobject-2.0' found
 No package 'gmodule-no-export-2.0' found
 configure: error: This package requires GLib >= 2.34.0 to compile.
```

How can I resolve these dependancies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install gstreamer? You can find Windows installers from here: http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/download/

Make sure to grab both the normal and -devel .msi files.

After installing those you should have gstreamer and all its dependencies in `C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86`. Test and make sure it is working! You'll also have a new environment variable `GSTREAMER_1_0_ROOT_X86` which points to this directory.

So, in MSYS, make sure you have `GSTREAMER_1_0_ROOT_X86\bin` in your `PATH`, and add `GSTREAMER_1_0_ROOT_X86\lib\pkgconfig` to your `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`.

Hopefully everything should now work.

**Edit:** It is important to install gstreamer to the default location, under `C:\gstreamer`, as it seems both the runtime and development files have this path hard coded.

A quick search of the gnome bugzilla turns up at least [one bug acknowledging this problem](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=679115).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Given that I installed gstreamer packages in D drive these commands in msys let me to configure GES: 1)PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/d/gstreamer/1.0/x86/lib/pkgconfig:/c/mingw/lib/pkgconfig" 2)export PKG_CONFIG PKG_CONFIG_PATH 3)./configure --prefix=$HOME . However I can't compile GES with "make all install" because it says "cc1.exe: warning: c:/gstreamer/1.0/x86/lib/glib-2.0/include: No such file or directory In file included from d:/gstreamer/1.0/x86/include/glib-2.0/glib/galloca.h:34:0 from d:/gstreamer/1.0/x86/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:32, from ../ges/ges.h:23, from ges.c:21".

Comment: and after this warning it gives me fatal error : "d:/gstreamer/1.0/x86/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:34:24: fatal error: glibconfig.h: No such file or directory  #include <glibconfig.h> make[3]: *** [libges_1.0_la-ges.lo] Error 1 make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/Benas/gstreamer-editing-services-1.2.1/ges' make[2]: *** [all] Error 2 make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/Benas/gstreamer-editing-services-1.2.1/ges'make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1 make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1 make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/Benas/gstreamer-editing-services-1.2.1' make: *** [all] Error 2".

Comment: Can you confirm that the file `D:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\lib\glib-2.0\include\glibconfig.h` exists?

Comment: Can you paste the gcc command that make is trying to run when you get that error?

Comment: The last thing Mingw Msys prints before warning and error is : "make[3]: Entering directory `/home/Benas/gstreamer-editing-services-1.2.1/ges';   CC       libges_1.0_la-ges.lo;".

Comment: Run with `make V=1` so you get the verbose output.

Comment: It says: /bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..    -I.. -mms-bitfields -Id:/gstreamer/1.0/x86
/include/gstreamer-1.0 -Id:/gstreamer/1.0/x86/include/glib-2.0 -I/c/gstreamer/1.0/x86/lib/glib-2.0/include   -mms-bitfie
lds -Id:/gstreamer/1.0/x86/include/gstreamer-1.0 -Id:/gstreamer/1.0/x86/include/glib-2.0 -I/c/gstreamer/1.0/x86/lib/glib
-2.0/include   -mms-bitfields -Id:/gstreamer/1.0/x86/include/gstreamer-1.0 -Id:/gstreamer/1.0/x86/include/glib-2.0 -I/c/
gstreamer/1.0/x86/lib/glib-2.0/include

Comment: -mms-bitfields -Id:/gstreamer/1.0/x86/include/gstreamer-1.0 -Id:/gstreamer/1.0/
x86/include/glib-2.0 -I/c/gstreamer/1.0/x86/lib/glib-2.0/include   -mms-bitfields -Id:/gstreamer/1.0/x86/include/gstream
er-1.0 -Id:/gstreamer/1.0/x86/include/glib-2.0 -I/c/gstreamer/1.0/x86/lib/glib-2.0/include   -Wall -Wdeclaration-after-s
tatement -Wvla -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wf
ormat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wold-style-definition -Winit-self

Comment: -Wmissing-include-dirs -Waddress -Waggregate-retur
n -Wno-multichar -Wnested-externs  -g     -DGST_USE_UNSTABLE_API -Id:/gstreamer/1.0/x86/include/libxml2   -mms-bitfields
 -Id:/gstreamer/1.0/x86/include/glib-2.0 -I/c/gstreamer/1.0/x86/lib/glib-2.0/include   -g -O2 -MT libges_1.0_la-ges.lo -
MD -MP -MF .deps/libges_1.0_la-ges.Tpo -c -o libges_1.0_la-ges.lo `test -f 'ges.c' || echo './'`ges.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -I.. -mms-bitfields -Id:/gstreamer/1.0/x86/include/gstreamer-1.0 -Id:/gs
treamer/1.0/x86/include/glib-2.0 -I/c/gstreamer/1

Comment: .0/x86/lib/glib-2.0/include -mms-bitfields -Id:/gstreamer/1.0/x86/inclu
de/gstreamer-1.0 -Id:/gstreamer/1.0/x86/include/glib-2.0 -I/c/gstreamer/1.0/x86/lib/glib-2.0/include -mms-bitfields -Id:
/gstreamer/1.0/x86/include/gstreamer-1.0 -Id:/gstreamer/1.0/x86/include/glib-2.0 -I/c/gstreamer/1.0/x86/lib/glib-2.0/inc
lude -mms-bitfields -Id:/gstreamer/1.0/x86/include/gstreamer-1.0 -Id:/gstreamer/1.0/x86/include/glib-2.0 -I/c/gstreamer/
1.0/x86/lib/glib-2.0/include -mms-bitfields -Id:/gstreamer/1.0/x86/include/gstreamer-1.0

Comment: -Id:/gstreamer/1.0/x86/include/
glib-2.0 -I/c/gstreamer/1.0/x86/lib/glib-2.0/include -Wall -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wvla -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing
-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wold
-style-definition -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs -Waddress -Waggregate-return -Wno-multichar -Wnested-externs -g -DG
ST_USE_UNSTABLE_API -Id:/gstreamer/1.0/x86/include/libxml2 -mms-bitfields -Id:/gstreamer/1.0/x86/include/glib-2.0 -I/c/g

Comment: streamer/1.0/x86/lib/glib-2.0/include -g -O2 -MT libges_1.0_la-ges.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libges_1.0_la-ges.Tpo -c ges.c
-DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o .libs/libges_1.0_la-ges.o

Comment: Looks like the problem is down to make using the wrong include directory: `-I/c/gstreamer/1.0/x86/lib/glib-2.0/include`. Not sure exactly where the problem is, you could try checking in `D:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\lib\pkgconfig\glib-2.0.pc` to see if it's using `/c/` instead of `/d/`. If so, you can try editing the .pc file, or simply reinstall gstreamer to your C:\ drive.

Comment: Deleting Gstreamer from D:/gstreamer and installing to C:/gstreamer actually solved the problem. Could you please copy that last comment and make another answer so that I could accept it and other people would be able to find it faster?

Comment: I've edited it in to my original answer, does it look good to you?